# Maintain original FK column when adding new navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have the classes:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Code first migrations creates the following tables:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Companies",
    c => new
        {
            CompanyId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.CompanyId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Employees",
    c => new
        {
            EmployeeId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Company_CompanyId = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.EmployeeId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Companies", t => t.Company_CompanyId)
    .Index(t => t.Company_CompanyId);
```

Now I want to add the Company property to the Employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to bind the new property to the existing column without changing the DB schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First map the association:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.Employees)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CompanyId);
```

Then tell EF to map the property `CompanyId` to the column `Company_CompanyId`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(e => e.CompanyId)
            .HasColumnName("Company_CompanyId");
```

Comment: Why is the first part needed? Shouldn't it be mapped by convention?

Comment: Maybe I was missing something, but the HasColumnName started to work when I explicitly mapped the relationship

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the solution proposed by @GertArnold. Following the same idea, you could also use [Data annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) to resolve the same problem:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company"),Column("Company_CompanyId")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```